# JavaScript/jQuery: Validate Checkbox & Dropdown Pairing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm teaching myself JavaScript/jQuery. I have three pairs of checkboxes and dropdowns I want to validate:

[code screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Emp.png)

I want to validate that both parts of a pair are selected:

-- If a checkbox is checked, a value is also selected from the associated dropdown

-- Or, if a value is selected from a dropdown, the associated checkbox must be checked

I don't want to enable/disable the checkbox or dropdown during the process. I want to allow the user to check/select what they will, then check to see if both parts of a given pair are checked and selected on submit.

JSFiddle for the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/6y6e0aod/5/

I spent a few hours on SO and googling in general, but couldn't find an example quite like this. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 1
  <select>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 2
  <select>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 3
  <select>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br /><br />
<button>submit data</button>
```

Comment: Then you might have to add a empty option in the select, else by default the first option will be marked as selected

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdga6bLt/1/ ?

Comment: A belated 'thanks!' to all who answered. I had a solution in mind for this, but it was overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a empty option to the select so that we can force the user to select one, then in the click handler of the button we can see whether if there is any checked checkbox where the select is empty like

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  var $invalid = $('input:checkbox:checked + select:has([value=""]:selected)');
  if ($invalid.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Need to select a value for: ' + $invalid.map(function() {
      return this.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim();
    }).get().join(', '));
    return;
  }
  //it is valid so do your stuff here
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 1
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 2
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 3
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<button id="submit">submit data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, but first wrap all the form in a div and wrap texts like `Vehicle 1` within a span. Then try the following code, click run to test

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var errors = validateCouple($('#myForm'));
  errors.length && alert(errors.join('\r\n'));
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }
})

function validateCouple($el) {
  var errors = [];
  $el.find('div').each(function() {
    var $div = $(this),
      $cbx = $div.find('input:checkbox'),
      $select = $div.find('select'),
      $span = $div.find('span');

    if ($cbx.prop('checked') && !$select.val()) {
      errors.push("Please select a value for " + $span.html());
    } else if ($select.val() && !$cbx.prop('checked')) {
      errors.push("Please enable " + $span.html());
    }
  })
  return errors;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myForm">

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><span>Vehicle 1</span>
    <select>
      <option></option>
      <option>Car</option>
      <option>Truck</option>
      <option>Van</option>
      <option>Motorcycle</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>Vehicle 2</span>
    <select>
      <option>Car</option>
      <option>Truck</option>
      <option>Van</option>
      <option>Motorcycle</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>Vehicle 3</span>
    <select>
      <option>Car</option>
      <option>Truck</option>
      <option>Van</option>
      <option>Motorcycle</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
  <button>submit data</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can help for your scenario

```
$("input,select").change(function() {
    if($(this).prop("tagName") == "SELECT" && $(this).val() != "SELECT")     {
       $(this).siblings('input').prop("checked",true)
    } 
    else if($(this).prop("tagName") == "SELECT" && $(this).val() == "SELECT")     {
       $(this).siblings('input').prop("checked",false)
    } else if(($(this).prop("tagName") == "INPUT") && $(this).prop("checked") == true) {  $(this).siblings('select').children('option:eq(1)').prop("selected","selected");
    } else if(($(this).prop("tagName") == "INPUT") && $(this).prop("checked") == false) {        $(this).siblings('select').children('option:eq(0)').prop("selected","selected");
    }
})


<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 1
  <select>
   <option>SELECT</option>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 2
  <select>
     <option>SELECT</option>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">Vehicle 3
  <select>
  <option>SELECT</option>
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
    <option>Van</option>
    <option>Motorcycle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br /><br />
<button>submit data</button>

</button>
```